# How to create a List of Existing Buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a 100 buttons on Windows Forms using Toolbox and I have given them a specific name for each row and column for example the first row is called A and first column is called 1 , the last row ends with the letter J and the last column ends with the number 10 . So it appears as a 10x10 array. What I am trying to do is add those buttons into a list either with a loop . On properties under design I have given them their equivalent name to make it easier. What would be the best way to add them into a list ?

Comment: Post an example of the names of these controls and we can show you how to build a list of them in a structure that puts them "in order" so you can access them by either 2D array syntax or by "key" with their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're already in a "list" in that to appear on the Form they must be a member of some existing Control's `.Controls` collection, and you can query it. Suppose they're just straight on the Form, not in a Panel etc:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
```

If you truly want a `List<Button>`, add `.ToList()` onto the end

--

If you have other buttons on the Form that you don't want being returned, then pick on something common about those buttons you do want, like "they all have a two-character name":

```
this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Name.Length == 2)
```

Of course, if you've also stuck a Button called OK, then this is defeated - but the "something common about them that no other button has" is *something you can influence* - rename your OK button if it's being picked up accidentally

---

If they're in their own Panel, it could be a good way of segregating them from other Buttons:

```
thePanelName.Controls.OfType<Button>()
```